# Android Library Project containing .jar

Tags: android, jar

I have a Android Library Project containing all the classes and resources I need for my application. But when I'm trying to create a new android project based entirely on my library project I'm running into trouble.

The library project contains several .jar with their own xml:schemes resulting in the following error : 
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hideMethod' in package 'my.library'.

Iv'e tried to copy the attrs.xml into the new project/values folder but I'm just getting an "Attribute already defined" -error.

If you have some tip to point me in the right direction it would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: have u copied jar files in libs folder >

Comment: Yes I have done that, still the same error.

Comment: Try exporting entries from your library. In Eclipse open properties of your library project and go to Java Build Path -> Order and Export and check libraries you want to export to your application.

Comment: Good advice but unfortunately it didn't help. Iv'e managed to get it working now but I have to copy all layout.xml with custom xmlschemes into my new project which doesn't feel like a great solution. Also I have to add all .jar to the new projects, I would like to just have them in the lib project.

Answer (score 1):

Compile your library proj. which will generate .jar in its /bin folder. Then from your main project, go to properties>Libraries and add path to the .jar file of your library proj. Apply clean build of your main proj. It must be solved your problem. I also faced the same problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do any difference. Also I need to have my project as a library project because I use values from strings.xml in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Have you tried to export your library project to JAR. Follow this: Right click on project, select Export, In Java section, Select JAR.. This will package your lib. proj. into jar. Then add this .jar to build path of your main proj.

Comment: That won't work since my project contains layout.xmls. I've come to the conclusion that the problem is that the package name in the xml name space will be wrong. Iv'e tried to use the http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto namespace but can't get it to work.

Comment: Then to access resource from your library proj. simple import or include it in your build path. You will get access to all the resources of a lib proj. :)

Comment: Refer to this image, where I've used android-core as a library proj. and bbb-android as a main proj. http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/0ggw1qkp0ufi7m3jng_Test2.png

Comment: Thanks for the image, it looks like it could be useful. Do you know if its possible to have the new project completely based on the library project? For example if I have Google Analytics in my library project, will I still have to include the googleAnalytics .jar in the new project?

Comment: Yes, you just to give path to google analytics lib proj or alternatively you can export that project to .jar and can add to your build path